# Cache an actionresult for the lifetime of the application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching

What would be the best way to cache an actionresult forever, that is untill the application is restarted.

```
// Cache this result forever, it will reset on app restart
[OutputCache(Duration=999999)]
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult Footer()
{
    if (HttpContext.Application != null && HttpContext.Application.AllKeys.Contains("Version"))
        return Content(HttpContext.Application["Version"].ToString());

    return null;
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I don't know a better way. You can create your own attribute `ForeverOutputCache`, which will set `Duration = Int32.MaxValue` in constructor, but this is almost same approach.

Comment: @AlexanderYezutov might want to add it as an answer, better for your rep ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know a better way. You can create your own attribute `ForeverOutputCache`, which will set `Duration = Int32.MaxValue` in constructor, but this is almost same approach.